# Javascript перестает работать при смене вкладки браузера

Tags: javascript, canvas

[Вот пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxT9ALEguGVqp6L0ImAc?p=preview) на рабочий код.

```
1. Запустите, колесо крутится несколько секунд, все норм.
2. Запустите колесо предварительно обновив страницу, пока колесо крутится погуляйте по вкладкам браузера, через несколько минут вернитесь, оно еще крутится, почему?

<div>
    <canvas class="the_canvas" id="myDrawingCanvas" width="434" height="434">
        <p class="noCanvasMsg" align="center">Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas.<br/>Please try another.</p>
    </canvas> 
</div>
```

SPIN

Answer (score 1):

Потому что при смене вкладки - в зависимости от браузера - его активные компоненты могут уходить в спячку. Попробуй через setTimeout кванты времени дергать - это на моей памяти не засыпает

Answer (score 0):

Современные браузеры ради экономии энергии и общей производительности в целом, увеличивают интервал вызова setInterval и setTimeout до 1 раза в секунду. Вообще, для анимации рекомендуют использовать requestAnimationFrame, но пример ниже демонстрирует, что и requestAnimationFrame тоже вызывается в неактивной вкладке реже чем обычно.

```js
var div1 = $('#setTimeout'),
    div2 = $('#setInterval'),
    div3 = $('#requestAnimationFrame'),
    i1 = 0,
    i2 = 0,
    i3 = 0;

function timer(){
  div1.html(++i1);
  setTimeout(timer, 100);
}
timer();

setInterval(function(){div2.html(++i2);}, 100)

function timerRequestAnimationFrame(){
  div3.html(Math.round(++i3/6));
  requestAnimationFrame(timerRequestAnimationFrame);
}

timerRequestAnimationFrame()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="setTimeout"></div>
<div id="setInterval"></div>
<div id="requestAnimationFrame"></div>
```